# AWS - How do I load a saved environment configuration from one application to another application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS - Elastic Beanstalk, I am trying to move an ec2 instance from one application into another. I saved the environment configuration for the ec2 instance. Then I went to the application that I want to move it to, but when I go to saved configurations, it doesn't show up. Did I miss a step somewhere? I thought I was able to launch new environments from saved configurations.

On the original ec2 instance, I clicked on "Actions" then "Save Configuration". Then I clicked on the application that I want to move the ec2 instance to, and clicked on "Saved Configurations". The saved configuration doesn't show up. I also clicked on Load, but it doesn't give me the option for the Environment I'm trying to move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say ec2 configuration I am sure you mean AWS Elasticbeanstalk application configuration. There is no ec2 configuration that you can save in AWS EB.

When you save AWS EB configuration its scope is within the APP. You won't see saved configuration of `Application-A` in `Application-B` and it does make sense. If you want to see it then you will need to copy configuration of `Application-A` to `Application-B` in S3.

AWS EB configurations are saved in your S3. So if you want to copy configuration of Application A into Application B, here are the steps (replace region and account id with yours):

- Go to Application-A environment and save configuration
- Go to S3 bucket of your AWS EB s3://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-598636547766/resources/templates/APPLICATION-A/
- Copy the configuration you saved
- Go to s3://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-598636547766/resources/templates/APPLICATION-B/    (if no APPLICATIOn-B folder, create one)
- Paste the configuration
- Go to Application-B environment, click Saved Configuration, now you should see the config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just now seeing this. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Okay that worked. I didn't know about the resources folder. Thank you for your help!